# how to add query in to setup queries room database for populate db with some inital value

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I am trying to add Room DB in my app. I need to add some master data in my table while init the db. Is there any way to do that like addSetUpQuery()

```
Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, KeepiDB::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_2_3)
                .addSetUPQuery("Query here")
                .build()
```

Comment: You can add using Room.databaseBuilder().addCallback(myCallBack) set call back. Make call back that implements RoomDatabase.Callback() and inside onOpen(db..). You can do any crud operations via DAO

Comment: Thanks @MD Can you please show me any example

Comment: See my answer for more details

Answer (score 1):

I saw you basic way of how you can do?

Init Room Database like below

```
 val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    WordRoomDatabase::class.java,
                    "Word_database"
                ).addCallback(WordDatabaseCallback()).build() // set my own callback here
```

And implement `WordDatabaseCallback` like

```
private class WordDatabaseCallback(
        private val scope: CoroutineScope
    ) : RoomDatabase.Callback() {

        override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onOpen(db)
            INSTANCE?.let { database ->
                scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    populateDatabase(database.wordDao())
                }
            }
        }

        suspend fun populateDatabase(wordDao: WordDao) {

            //Clearing all the data from table  
            wordDao.deleteAll()

            //Adding record 
            var word = Word("Hello")
            wordDao.insert(word)

            //Adding record 
            word = Word("World!")
            wordDao.insert(word)
        }
    }
```

`WordDao` is my **DAO** and I am trying insert/delete data via it

For more details you can see below links

1. [Link1](https://medium.com/@srinuraop/database-create-and-open-callbacks-in-room-7ca98c3286ab)
2. [Link2](https://android.jlelse.eu/pre-populate-room-database-6920f9acc870)
3. [Link3](https://gist.github.com/AdamMc331/5d48220875ce6b8bf0a0c0396ec8a0c0)

Comment: I believe that this would delete all the records and then add the initial data every time the App is run. To add the records just once when the database is created you'd override the **onCreate** method rather than the onOpen method, this being how I would interpret *I need to add some master data in my table while init the db*

Comment: @MikeT yes you're right but this is just a basic way. I saw Delete only for knowledge purpose